# Template Function Specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I am doing an exercise on templates and I am now dealing with specializations. I have defined a function `T read_val(T& v)` that takes input from `cin` and compiles the `T val` inside my `template<typename T> struct S`. I wish to specialize this function to types `int`, `double`, `char`, `string` but, when I am trying to do it, I'm keep getting errors. Here is what I wrote:

Header.h:

```
#ifndef Templates_Header_h
#define Templates_Header_h
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct S
{
private:
    T val;
public:
    S() : val{} {};
    T* get();
    T* get() const;
    T set();
    T operator=(const T&);
    T read_val(T& v);
    void print_val() const;
};

template<typename T>
void S<T>::print_val() const
{
    cout << "Value is: " << val << endl;
}

template<typename T>
T* S<T>::get()
{
    T* p = &val;
    return p;
}

template<typename T>
T S<T>::set()
{
    T newvalue;
    cout << "Type new value: ";
    cin >> newvalue;
    S<T>::val = newvalue;
    return S<T>::val;
}

template<typename T>
T S<T>::operator=(const T&)
{
    T val1;
    val1 = val;
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
T* S<T>::get() const
{
    T* p = &val;
    return p;
}

template<typename T>
T S<T>::read_val(T &v)
{
    cout << "Type Value: ";
    cin >> v;
    return S<T>::val = v;
}

#endif
```

Header.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

template <>
struct S <int>  // Specialization
{
private:
    int val;
public:
    S() : val{0} {};
};

template<>
struct S<char>  // Specialization
{
private:
    char val;
public:
    S() : val{'0'} {};
};

template <>
struct S<double>  // Specialization
{
private:
    double val;
public:
    S() : val{0.0} {};
};

template <>
struct S<string>  // Specialization
{
private:
    string val;
public:
    S() : val{""} {};
};

template<>
struct S<vector<int>>  // Specialization
{
private:
    vector<int> val;
public:
    S() : val{0} {};
};

template<> // !! ERROR !!
int read_val(int& v)
{
    cout << "Type a value: ";
    cin >> v;
    return v;
}
```

Xcode is reporting "No function template matches function template specialization 'read_val'". I was surfing the net reading examples and references but I cannot solve it. Can you help me? I need an example to fix it in mind.
Thanks!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ look there for 'class templates' and see an example of how to use it. Looks like you didn't understand the point of templates and their usage.

Comment: @AlexLop. I looked at but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: There should be no CPP file for a template header. Your implementation is already in the header file!
Create main.cpp with:
`#include "Header.h"`
`#include <iostream>`
`int main()`
`{`
`    S<int> my_S;`
`    int val;`
`    S.read_val(&val);`
`    std::cout << "The read value is " << val << std::endl;`
`    return 0;`
`}`

Or something like that, I didn't compile it...

Comment: Ok, I have already moved all into header file. I thought it was more correct to split the file in two. It is the first time I am dealing with templates.

Comment: That's why I referred you to an example. Because according to your implementation I see that you missed the point of templates.
You need to define it only once (no need to rewrite it manually for each type like int, float, etc., the compiler will do it for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no CPP file for a template header. Your implementation is already in the header file! 
Create main.cpp with:

```
#include "Header.h" 
#include <iostream> 
int main() 
{ 
    S<int> my_S;
    int val;

    my_S.read_val(val/*by ref*/);
    std::cout << "The read value is " << val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or something like that, I didn't compile it...
According to your implementation I see that you missed the point of templates. You need to define it only once (no need to rewrite it manually for each type like int, float, etc., the compiler will do it for you).

Comment: I defined them explicitly because it was part of my homework! I know that it would be useless and verbose do it...